# Any suggestions on creating xxhdpi,xxxhdpi watches in the android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, wear-os, watch, android-wear-2.0

Since I don't have watches with xxhdpi and xxxhdpi,I've tried manually configuring an AVD to support both the resolution watches in emulator.

I'm trying to create a new profile for this(Parameters are added in attached screenshot)

But It is creating 480*480 hdpi watch device.As per DisplayMetrics provided by android, 480*480 will have xxhigh

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no XXHDPI or XXXHDPI WearOS hardware in production (or announced); [the highest screen density in the wild is 348dpi](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lbKhNnFBARrT5TVo3bkyp1UzT0S5Iahy3W9dAQf_sfc/edit#gid=0), which is still in the XHDPI bucket.

So, I'd conclude that the WearOS emulator hasn't been built to support densities higher than XHDPI.

Comment: Thanks for the update,Could you please let me know from where you got the link?

Comment: Just for an Info @Sting,Actually i'm able to create XXHDPI device from AVD with this properties DPI- 360,Screenheight-213.33333,ScreenWidth 213.33333

Comment: That list is crowd-sourced, and I got it from https://www.reddit.com/r/WearOS. AFAIK, there's no official equivalent.

Comment: Okay,Thanks for the info